# How download a preview of a webpage client-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I'd like to get an image of an URL provide by user.

I thought to make a `fetch` or an AJAX request to get the HTML code and then convert it with [HTML2CANVAS](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is what I tested directly in the console of Trello website, line per line:

```js
function preview_ws(url) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + url,
    success: function(result) {
      html = document.createElement("html");
      html.innerHTML = result;
    }
  });
}

preview_ws("https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props")

// many errors like GET https://trello.com/images/components.png 404
// the HTML seems to correspond (title is Vue.JS)

html2canvas(html).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});

// then, I have errors:
```

Then I have errors:

```js
Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-storage-access-by-user-activation' is an invalid sandbox flag.
Promise {<rejected>: "Unable to find element in cloned iframe"}
Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe
```

I also tried with:

```js
html2canvas(html.querySelector("body")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

but I get the sames errors.

So how can I make what I want? I' m reminding you I want something on the client-side.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You pass a parameter to your function, `url`, yet never use it. Do you see any errors in console? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're not waiting for the ajax request to complete - check what `html` is before you attempt to use it

Comment: I edit my code, I was wrong when I wrote the snippet. All errors I got is here, with all my code (I tested directly in console). The HTML is what I want (`//the HTML seems to correspond (title is Vue.JS)`)

Comment: What's `html` in `html2canvas(html)`?

Comment: `html` in `html2canvas` is the element that I created when Ajax successed

Comment: Which occurs *after* you attempt to use it...

Comment: Also `html` would be out of scope. Since it's defined in `preview_ws()` we cannot access it outside that function.

Comment: I don't use `var` keyword, so I can access outside function normally. More over, I log `html` and it corresponds to the page I want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  URL <input id="url" type="text" value="https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props" /> <button id="go">Fetch</button>
</div>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function preview_ws(u) {
    console.log("Fetch", u);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + u,
      success: function(result) {
        var $ht = $("<html>");
        $ht.html(result);
        console.log("HTML", $ht[0]);
        html2canvas($ht[0].body).then(canvas => {
          $("#preview").html(canvas);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  $("#go").click(function() {
    var url = $("#url").val();
    if (url !== "") {
      preview_ws(url);
    }
  });
});
```

Here we create an HTML Object and then populate it with the `results`. We can then pass this to the html2canvas as described in the documentation.

Comment: Get error : [Console view](https://i.imgur.com/bcHLZma.png)

Comment: @ArthurFontaine the error, *Cannot read property 'ownerProperty' of undefined*, suggests that something being passed into `html2canvas` is not correct. Please pastebin or screen shot the entire console result.